# Create symlink to the current jar package after mvn package

Tags: java, maven, jar

My jar file name is configured in pom.xml like this:

```
<finalName>MyApp-${project.version}</finalName>
```

I would like Maven ('mvn package') to create a symlink to the current jar file every time I run it, so that I have two files:

`MyApp-1.0.3.jar`
`MyApp.jar` (which is `"ln -s MyApp-1.0.3.jar MyApp.jar"`)

Comment: You should be able to do that using some plugin that allows you to either create links or execute shell script (or just create the jar twice). But why would you want to do that? Why not just work with the versioned jar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Exec Maven Plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/examples/example-exec-for-java-programs.html) as below to achieve this goal:

```
 <plugin>
   <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
   <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
   <version>1.6.0</version>
   <executions>
     <execution>
       <id>Version Calculation</id>
       <phase>verify</phase>
       <goals>
         <goal>exec</goal>
       </goals>
       <configuration>
         <executable>ln</executable>
         <arguments>
            <argument>-fnsv</argument>
            <argument>target/MyApp-${project.version}.jar</argument>
            <argument>MyApp.jar</argument>
         </arguments>
       </configuration>
     </execution>
   </executions>
 </plugin>
```

Use below goals to execute it:

```
mvn clean verify
```

Comment: FYI: `verify` is goal is used to be on safer side to execute the ln command post creation of jar in `package` goal.

Answer (score 1):

You can use symlink task/goal of ant-run plugin

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.8</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <configuration>
                <target>
                    <symlink link="${project.build.directory}/${project.artifactId}.jar"
                             resource="${project.build.directory}/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}.jar"/>
                </target>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
                <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

If you want the symlinks to have relative path, you can give relative path in resource like below

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.8</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <configuration>
                <target>
                    <symlink link="${project.build.directory}/${project.artifactId}.jar"
                             resource="./${project.artifactId}-${project.version}.jar"/>
                </target>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
                <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: This works in my Macbook, but failed in my Linux server.

Comment: Works here, with Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: Instead of ${project.artifactId}-${project.version}.jar, you should use ${project.build.finalName}.jar